# Tomcat SSL Configuration

Tags: ssl, tomcat6

I received a SSL cert to use for a Tomcat 6.0 server, ready to use.

I configured Tomcat to use it with the following in server.xml:

```xml
<Connector 
    port="8443" maxThreads="200"
    scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
    keystoreFile="C:\Tomcat 6.0\ssl\cert" keystorePass="*****"
    clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

I started Tomcat using the command prompt so I could see any error message as they happened.  There were none.

The results for accessing different URLS:

- http://localhost -> normal page loads fine
- https://localhost -> browser claims page cannot be found
- https://localhost:8443 -> page cannot be found
- http://localhost:8443 -> offers a certificate, after accepted redirects to https://localhost (I suspect the https:// urls initially offer the certificate which is automatically accepted by the browser, as it was issued by Verisign)

How to fix?

Edit: I've also tried port="443".  Same result.

Answer (score 0):

Do you require SSL on both 8443 and 443?

If all you need is 443 (the standard HTTP port), you can simply change the port="8443" to "443" and https:// URLs should work fine.

EDIT:
OK, so if you've made the change and bounced tomcat and it's *still* listening on 8443 then there must be another connector specified which is listening on 8443.

Here's my connector configuration from my server.xml

```
<Connector 
    port="8080" 
    redirectPort="443" 
    maxSpareThreads="75" 
    maxThreads="150" 
    minSpareThreads="25" 
    compression="on" 
    compressionMinSize="2048" 
    noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata" 
    compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/javascript,application/xml">
</Connector>


<Connector 
    port="443" 
    minProcessors="5" 
    maxProcessors="75" 
    keystorePass="*****" 
    enableLookups="true" 
    disableUploadTimeout="true" 
    acceptCount="100" 
    debug="0" 
    scheme="https" 
    secure="true" 
    clientAuth="false" 
    sslProtocol="TLS" 
    compression="on" 
    compressionMinSize="2048" 
    noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata" 
    compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/javascript,application/xml">
</Connector>
```

That results in traffic coming in on 8080 being (internally) redirected to the connector on port 443.  Traffic from 443 doesn't have any redirect directive.

I'd do a grep of your configurations for 8443 to make sure another one hasn't sneaked in somewhere.

Comment: I've edited my question to reflect that I've already tried this :(

Answer (score 0):

I looks like you referenced a cert file in the keystoreFile attribute... if that file is actually a cert file you should use something like this

```
SSLCertificateFile="C:\Tomcat 6.0\ssl\cert"
```

... if that is correct (that the file a cert) then you will also need a key, for example:

```
SSLCertificateKeyFile="C:\Tomcat 6.0\ssl\cert.key"
```

If you have intermediate certs that you need in the CA chain, add:

```
SSLCertificateChainFile=
```