# TomCat bound to 443 but won't load an https site except on 8443 (Running with IIS, Windows 2k8)

Tags: tomcat, iis, ssl, tomcat7

**Quick Version:** 
I want to stop using 8443 SSL on a website hosted on TomCat and use 443 instead. Everything works on 8443, nothing works when I change port to 443.

**Long Version:**

I've been searching and found similar questions but with answers that didn't work for me.

I have TomCat running on a machine with IIS. I limited IIS to IP Address A using the netsh commands. Results Here:

```
IP addresses present in the IP listen list:
-------------------------------------------
    #.#.#.A
```

I then set the TomCat connector and gave it an address of IP Address B.  I can verify that the TomCat has bound 443, 80, 7990 and 8443 on IP Address B using the NetStat command. Results of that here:

```
 TCP    #.#.#.B:80       0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       6324
 [tomcat7.exe]
  TCP    #.#.#.B:443      0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       6324
 [tomcat7.exe]
  TCP    #.#.#.B:7990     0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       6324
 [tomcat7.exe]
  TCP    #.#.#.B:8443     0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       6324
 [tomcat7.exe]
```

If I use this connector info, it works great on 8443 (https), 80 (http), and 7990 (http). Https has a valid certificate everything works.

```
<Connector 
port="80" 
protocol="HTTP/1.1"
connectionTimeout="20000"
useBodyEncodingForURI="true"
redirectPort="8443"
compression="on"
address="#.#.#.B" 
compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,application/json,application/javascript,application/x-javascript"/>

<Connector 
    port="8443"
    address="#.#.#.B" 
    maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
    SSLEnabled="true"
    maxThreads="150"
    minSpareThreads="25"
    maxSpareThreads="75"
    enableLookups="false"
    disableUploadTimeout="true"
    useBodyEncodingForURI="true"
    acceptCount="100"
    scheme="https"
    secure="true"
    clientAuth="false"
    sslProtocol="TLS" 
    keyAlias="xxxxxx"
    keystoreFile="<path to keystorefile>"
    keystorePass="xxxxxx"
/>
```

However, if I change it to 443 and I get page not available. I tried a redirctport to 8443 and that didn't work either.

Similar Questions I looked at:

- [Tomcat SSL Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898748/tomcat-ssl-configuration)
- [Trouble with SSL https connection on port 8443](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452505/trouble-with-ssl-https-connection-on-port-8443)

Is there another setting I'm missing somewhere?